# Media Queries acting weirdly

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, mobile-devices

I am using dream weaver to create a responsive about me page for my site (using the default about me template). When I use the dream weaver on-device previewing system, the page is fully responsive and on my iPhone it resizes perfectly fine to look like this:
[image: responsive preview]

However, when I upload the code to the website, the page no longer becomes responsive. It simply looks the same as it does on my laptop (as shown below)
[image: nonresponsive preview]

Why is this issue occurring?

The html page is [this](http://www.femtonation.com/AmroThabet.html). If you need me to post the code here as well, please tell me. Your help is much appreciated :)

Comment: I can't say I will answer the question, but pleas post the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For media queries to work on small screens, you need to include the viewport meta element in the head of your document. E.g.:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: This fixed it thanks :) It's weird that the template didn't have that included :/

Comment: Yes, it is strange. This is an essential element. Anyway, glad to help. :-)